# Is it possible to implement friends.getMutualFriends using FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I am looking for a way to implement friends.getMutualFriends of Facebook's Old REST API with FQL. The reasons are twofold:
1. getMutualFriends only returns a list of IDs, and I'd like to use a multi-query to fetch additional information for each returned ID (rather than make additional calls to Facebook)
2. I'd like to batch a few such calls together. batch.run is a bit limited (20 calls) and presumably slower than a multiquery.

Unfortunately, I probably can't use the friends table, because while the sourceID is of a user of my app, the targetID may not be a user of my app (Facebook won't even let me select the friends of the target even in a nested query, which is understandable due to privacy concerns.)
But since I **can** get the mutual friends using friends.getMutualFriends, I'm wondering if there's any FQL equivalent.